# How to save ANDROID_HOME permanently?

Tags: android, macos, sdk, path

**THE SITUATION:**

Everytime i have to do some operations in the console for an app i got the following error:

> ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH.

**THE SOLUTION:**

I have found the following solution: In order to specify the path of ANDROID_HOME I Copy paste these two lines in the console (that path is my own path to the folder android-sdk-macosx - you may have a different path):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

It works fine. But the fact is that the next time i open the Terminal i have to repeat the operation again.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i save this path as permanent in the MAC terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables in OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the command line do the following:

Edit the file `~/.profile` and add the two lines from your post.

`export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Any already open terminal windows you will need to source the file like this:

`. ~/.profile`

Any new terminal windows will load those settings automatically.

---

If you are doing Android development on Mac you may like http://LogRabbit.com for viewing your device logs.

Comment: I went to the user folder and type ls -a but i didn't find .profile